# how do I add to a total if an operation is repeated over and over by a user in VB?

Tags: visual-studio

Ok so I have a simple maze game and i'm trying to make it so that when the user wins, a random number of points between 1-7 is generated, which to be clear I got to work. What I can't figure out is when the user resets the game I want the points to stay displayed until the user wins again. When the user wins, I want another number between 1-7 to be added to the previous number, again and again. How do I add to a previous number?

Comment: Store the points to another variable?

Comment: how would you recommend  I do that?

Comment: Can you post some code, maybe we'll be able to help better then.

Answer (score 0):

Public Sub Form4_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

```
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim r2 As New Random

    Dim randoms1 = r2.Next(1, 20)
    Dim randoms = r.Next(1, 7)
    Integer.TryParse(Label3.Text, total)


    If PictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(finishLabel.Bounds) Then
        Label3.Text = 0
        Label3.Text = total + randoms
        total = Label3.Text
        PictureBox2.Location = New Point(350, 30)
    ElseIf Nothing Then
```

finally got it to work, here was what I was looking for.